# Axios returning parsed JSON data in ReactJS with an undefined value for file key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, axios, jsonparser

I am having an odd issue where my Laravel API is returning JSON data to my react front-end via Axios and then Axios is parsing the data and returning an **undefined** value for a specific key "file".

Ive added a **transformResponse** function to the Axios get method that logs the response before and after doing my own parsing and I still get the same result. Im also using the reviver parameter to log the value when the key is file.

```
api.get(`xxxxx`, {
            transformResponse: (res) => {
                console.log(res);

                const  data = JSON.parse(res, (key,value) => {
                    if (key === 'file' && value !== null) console.log(value);
        
                    return value;
                });

                console.log(data);

                return data;
            },
        }).then(res => {
```

The output of the **first** **log:**

```
{"data":{"value":{"value": 20,"users": [],"file":{"id":20,"fileable_id":2,"folder_id":21,"group_id":null,"name":"IMG_6274.jpg","size":4263000,"downloads":1,"created_at":"2023-11-01T17:24:17.000000Z","updated_at":"2023-11-01T17:24:29.000000Z","deleted_at":null,"extension":"jpg","size_formatted":"4.07 MB","full_url":"https:\/\/ca-dev-stor.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com\/club\/2\/fields\/38\/2b837cdd-ee95-49a9-992d-74211b4400da.jpg"}}}}
```

The output of the **second** **log:**

```
{
    "id": 20,
    "fileable_id": 2,
    "folder_id": 21,
    "group_id": null,
    "name": "IMG_6274.jpg",
    "size": 4263000,
    "downloads": 1,
    "created_at": "2023-11-01T17:24:17.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2023-11-01T17:24:29.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "extension": "jpg",
    "size_formatted": "4.07 MB",
    "full_url": "https://ca-dev-stor.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/club/2/fields/38/2b837cdd-ee95-49a9-992d-74211b4400da.jpg"
}
```

And the output of the **third log:**

```
{
    "data": {
        "value": {
            "value": 20,
            "users": [],
            "file": undefined
        }
    }
}
```

However if i take the original line and parse it as a string instead of from the response object i get no issue. Not sure how to fully reproduce this - mostly hoping someone has run into this issue before. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the issue.  If you are also not able to replicate it then this pretty strongly suggests that the issue isn't what/where you think it is.  Is this operation being invoked twice and you're looking at the wrong output?  How is ReactJS involved at all?  Without an example demonstrating the problem, there's likely not much we can do.

Comment: Thanks for the response @David. I have tried to produce a fiddle replicating the issue but can't seem to reproduce it. ReactJS tag is provided for context of the JS environment where this is occurring. I agree with your theory although unfortunately I can't provide the larger picture here for deeper inspection.